# What is the right eloquent relationship to use on sharing same product but different distributor?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

There is a portal where manufacturer supplies to distributors and orders from dealers are verified by their own distributor. Assuming that "Distributor X" has 40 stock balance for "Shampoo Blue". Whenever dealer order SB, DX will just need to verify the payment. Once the payment verified, it will deduct stock balance from DX and manufacturer will pack and ship out.

I can't figure out how to deduct stock balance from it.

Dealar - Place order
Distributor - Verify order and deduct stock balance.
Manufacturer - Pack and ship.

I tried using Many to Many, Has One Through and also Poly Many to Many.

```
companies
 - id integer
 - name string

products
 - id integer
 - name string
 - price decimal

orders
 - id integer
 - company_id integer
 - timestamps datetime
 - verified boolean

order_items
 - id integer
 - product_id integer
 - order_id integer

inventories
 - ??
 - ??
 - balance integer
 etc
```

What is the schema to create an Inventory model and what is the relationships(if the relationships exists in Laravel) I should use or need something else to perform SQL queries to deduct balance of the particular product?

Many companies may have different products balance, whenever the dealer order it will deduct from the company balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many to Many is the right relation to apply.

If your product can be from more than 1 distributor (1 to N) and one distributor can have more than one product (1 to N) then in conclusion you'll have N to N (Many to Many) relation.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't meet my requirement. Don't forget the product is shared by different companies and inventory balance is between company and product. Stress! haha

Comment: @JunoFernando Buddy, that's still Many to Many.
Draw it on a piece of paper - draw few products, few companies and maybe few inventory balances if they are a separate table - then connect some possible and logical to you combinations with lines - if there's more than 1 line coming out of a single item, then it's Many to Many.

Comment: Yep, Many to Many is the correct relationship by adding additional column named 'balance' and in the model add ->withPivot('balance'). Thanks JCode.

Comment: @JunoFernando Glad I could help.